# Special characters in javascript alerts with phonegap & android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, special-characters, alert

i am developing an android "app" using phonegap.
I have trouble displaying special characters used in the german language (like ö ä ü) in javascript alert-boxes...

The Header of my index.html looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" charset="utf-8" />
```

Is there a way to display special characters correctly in alert boxes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to HTML escape the characters:

```
alert('&ouml; &auml; &uuml;');
```

produces the correct output for me.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesnt seem to work even when using jsfiddle.
But it works with escaping ä with \xE4 !
Please check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/CFgWN/1/

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by using the javascript unescape() function which decodes an encoded string.

Example: Third alert at http://jsfiddle.net/CFgWN/3/